# Proof explanation for Order of Subgroups, by Fraleigh

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Theorem: $G$ a cyclic group, $H < G$, $H = \langle a^s \rangle$ then $|H|=\frac{G}{\operatorname{gcd}(s,n)}.$

Proof:

Let $|H|=| \langle a^s \rangle |=m$ for $m$ smallest such that $(a^s)^m=e$

So $(a^s)^m=e$ if and only if $n|ms$.

How do we find $m$ smallest satisfying $n|ms$? Why does Fraleigh introduce Bezout's Identity, and how does the GCD help?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? (He uses Bezout's identity to show that $n\mid ms$ iff $\frac{n}{d} \mid m\frac{s}{d}$ where $d = \gcd(s,n)$, so that $m = \frac{n}{d}$ is the smallest $m$).

Comment: What is the intuition behind using the gcd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in Fraleigh uses Bezout's identity to show that $n∣ms$ iff $\frac{n}{d}\mid m\frac{s}{d}$ where $d=\gcd(s,n)$, so that $m=\frac{n}{d}$ is the smallest such $m$.

To see this another way, and perhaps see why the $\gcd$ is relevant, clearly we want the smallest $m$ such that $n\mid ms$. Now, $s$ contains some of the factors of $m$ (the product of those is $\gcd(n,s)$) and does not contain others. So to make $ms$ divisible by $n$, $m$ must be the product of those other factors. But this product is precisely $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)}$.

Comment: Is it fair to say that we are looking for the LCM of "s" and "n", and "m" is the number we must multiply "s" by in order to reach the LCM(s,n). 

In other words, you find the LCM of "n" and "s" by multiplying them together divided by the GCD(n,s). So LCM(n,s) = (n*s) / (gcd(n,s)).  So s * m = LCM(n,s).  So m = LCM(n,s) / s.  So m = n / GCD(n,s).  I apologize for the huge delay of my answer.

Comment: If that way of seeing the result makes intuitive sense to you, it is perfectly valid. So go with it :)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for your time!

Comment: @Kam You're welcome. If this response met your needs, please consider an upvote and/or accept.